# Extra figure in photo of sun

Tags: visible-light, sun, optics

[image: see the image]

I just captured a photo of sun in my mobile camera. And see the pic. Where there is an extra sun or a shape similar to it just below on the right side. What is this?[image: this is what i am talking about]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a photography question.

Comment: Then why did you answer it @StephenG?

Comment: @XcoderX Because it can be closed or migrated, but the OP may as well be told the answer one way or another as it's so simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare).

Basically it's a reflection due to light from a very bright source still being visible after bouncing off a lot of internal surfaces in the lens-camera system.

They are commonly see in photography.

As is typical , this one seems to be symmetric with the Sun about the center of the image.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: that is a light reflection which occurred inside your camera. the light from the sun enters the lens of the camera and is focused onto the imaging element, but part of that light bounces off the surface of the imaging chip and heads back towards the lens. part of it passes through the lens, exiting the camera, and part of it bounces back and heads for the chip a second time. there it forms a second image of the sun. for a camera with a single element lens, this reflection process is simple and usually forms a single secondary image. for a camera with a complex lens containing many separate lenses with air gaps between them, the reflection process is much more complex and a whole series of secondary images can form.

secondary images like this can be seen in animated films, but these are created artificially and added to the finished image to make it appear as if the scene was actually photographed with a "real" camera.

Comment: Why a photogram of a film would not show these secondary images per se?

Comment: Why there is only one of of them? As there are many reflections in all direction there will be many copy of sun with decreasing intensity.isn't it.